# how to descrypt an aes encryption from flutter in php

Tags: php, flutter, dart, encryption, aes

In my flutter app am using an encryption package called [encrypt](https://pub.dev/packages/encrypt) . and am able to encrypt my chat messages using this code

```
import 'package:encrypt/encrypt.dart';

class TextEncrypt {
  final _iv = IV.fromLength(16);
  final key = Key.fromLength(32);

  String decrypt(String text) {
    final enc = Encrypter(AES(key));
    final encrypted = Encrypted.fromBase64(text);
    return enc.decrypt(encrypted, iv: this._iv);
  }

  String encrypt(String text) {
    final enc = Encrypter(AES(key));
    return enc.encrypt(text, iv: _iv).base64;
  }
}
```

but the problem is that the encrypted part will be stored in mysql database and flutter local database ([sqflite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite)) too and when i want to build a website for the app using php mysql html css javascript. How will i be able to decrypt it back to its normal text using php or do you think that there might be a better way to encrypt it in the app and also be able to decrypt it in php aside from this method

Please if you don't understand what am saying and need more explanation please tell me

Comment: _encrypt_ uses SIC/CTR mode by default. What does your recent PHP code look like or what is the problem? Note that `IV.fromLength(16)` generates an IV consisting of 0x00 values which is insecure. For a given key, a random IV should be generated and passed to the decrypting side along with the ciphertext (typically concatenated). Similarly, `Key.fromLength(32)` generates an insecure key consisting of all 0x00 values.

Comment: @Topaco so which do you think will be the best approach to fix this issue

Comment: If I understood you correctly, your question is about decryption with PHP and a problem with it. For an analysis of the issue you would first have to post your PHP code and describe the exact problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the sample which can help you:

Flutter code:

```
import 'package:encrypt/encrypt.dart';

String decrypt(String encrypted) {
  final key = Key.fromUtf8("1245714587458888"); //hardcode combination of 16 character
  final iv = IV.fromUtf8("e16ce888a20dadb8"); //hardcode combination of 16 character

  final encrypter = Encrypter(AES(key, mode: AESMode.cbc));
  Encrypted enBase64 = Encrypted.from64(encrypted);
  final decrypted = encrypter.decrypt(enBase64, iv: iv);
  return decrypted;
}

String encrypt(String value) {
  final key = Key.fromUtf8("1245714587458745"); //hardcode 
  final iv = IV.fromUtf8("e16ce888a20dadb8"); //hardcode 

  final encrypter = Encrypter(AES(key, mode: AESMode.cbc));
  final encrypted = encrypter.encrypt(value, iv: iv);

  return encrypted.base64;
}
```

And the PHP code: (Enable openssl.dll Extension)

```
function encrypt($value){
    $key = '1245714587458888'; //combination of 16 character
    $iv = 'e16ce888a20dadb8'; //combination of 16 character
    $method = 'aes-128-cbc';
    $encryptedString = openssl_encrypt($value, $method,
        $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
    return base64_encode($encryptedString);
}

function decrypt($value){
    $key = '1245714587458888'; //combination of 16 character
    $iv = 'e16ce888a20dadb8'; //combination of 16 character
    $method = 'aes-128-cbc';
    $base64 = base64_decode($value);
    $decryptedString = openssl_decrypt($base64, $method,
        $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
    return $decryptedString;
}
```

Comment: I know that this solution is written for the OP question but you should place a **security warning** on your code as an **static IV is UNSECURE** - kindly use a randomly generated IV and pass it along with the ciphertext to the recipient for decryption, thank you.

Comment: I keep getting `Invalid argument(s): Invalid or corrupted pad block` whenever i want to decrypt and error when encrypting. I try to auto generate unique keys and iv for each chat room eg `Key.fromUtf8("4038474341130976")` and `IV.fromUtf8("gnw77gz0x2ckgtgf")` . Is there something am doing wrong or is the keys just wrong

Comment: But if i use your own dummy keys and iv it works very well